# Is there any limit on the number of scheduled queries in Google BigQuery per project?

Tags: google-bigquery, quota

I have scheduled few queries in Google BigQuery using Standard SQL but I want to know the maximum limit on number of queries that can be scheduled per project. I have used Schedule Query option in BigQuery to schedule my queries and currently I have scheduled around 20 queries, some of them run daily and some of them run weekly. Having knowledge on maximum limit would help me understand how many more queries I can schedule.

Answer (score 3):

No such limit for scheduled query itself. But those queries run under your project, so please be aware of all of the BQ limits: 
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#query_jobs